# Error con un botón de agregar a favoritos en react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, botón

estoy realizando una aplicación web con react y redux y tengo problemas con un boton:

La pagina  tiene 3 screen (home, favoritos , login) y un search dentro del home para buscar los personajes y puedes colocar el nombre de ellos y buscarlos si el nombre que colocaste en el search coincide con el de algunos de los personajes se mostrará una card, la cual contiene un BOTON (este es el del problema), este botón tiene una condición la cual verifica si este personaje se encuentra dentro de los favoritos, de ser así el botón figurará como delete y ejecuta una función para eliminar de favoritos y si NO está en favoritos el boton figurará como add y ejecutará una función para agregar a favoritos:

El Boton FUNCIONA BIEN en primera instancia puedo eliminar  y agregar a favoritos con un  solo click y cambia su apariencia (esto lo hace las veces que el usuario desee) , EL PROBLEMA APARECE CUANDO:
[escenario]
-una vez que dí click al botón agregar (el personaje se agregó correctamente) y luego me muevo a otra sección del sitio
-luego me vuelvo a colocar en el search y  vuelvo a colocar el nombre del mismo personaje que anteriormente lo habia agregado a fav : AHORA EL BOTON APARECE COMO DELETE PERO NO EJECUTA NINGUNA FUNCIÓN SIMPLEMENTE SE QUEDA Y NO EJECUTA NINGUNA FUNCIÓN.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import styles from '../home/home.module.css';
import {FontAwesomeIcon} from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import {faStar, faTrash} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import {removePoke, addFavPoke} from '../../actions/actions'
function Pikacard({stado, addFavPoke,removePoke, movies}){
console.log(movies.filter(x => x.names === stado.names).length);
    return (
        <>
        <div className="card w-75 mt-3">
        <div className="row">
       <img src={stado.img} className="rounded float-left" id={styles.imgpocke}></img>
       <div className="card-body p-3">
       <div className="float-left w-50">
       <p>{stado.names}</p>
        <p>{stado.valordepelea}</p>
        <p>{stado.type}</p>
       </div>
      <div className="float-right w-50">
          <p>{stado.habilidad}</p>
          <p>{stado.moves}</p>
      </div>
       </div>
       </div>
      <div className="card-body">
    <h5 className="card-title">No pierdas tiempo y añade a {stado.names} a tu lista de favoritos</h5>
    <p className="card-text">Todos el universo Pokemon te está esperando solo tienes que buscarlos</p>
    {movies.filter(x => x.names === stado.names).length > 0 & <button onClick={()=>removePoke(stado)} className="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrash}/> remove</button>}
    : <button  className="btn btn-success btn-sm" onClick={(e)=>addFavPoke(stado)} ><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faStar}/> Fav</button>
    </div>
   </div>
        </>
    )
   

}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        movies: state.moviesfav
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { removePoke, addFavPoke })(Pikacard);
```

Para ser más especifico el error con el boton estaria sucediendo acá

```
{movies.filter(x => x.names === stado.names).length > 0 & <button onClick={()=>removePoke(stado)} className="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrash}/> remove</button>}
    : <button  className="btn btn-success btn-sm" onClick={(e)=>addFavPoke(stado)} ><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faStar}/> Fav</button>
```

[aclaración movies es el array con los personajes favoritos que se encuentra dentro de mi store de redux]
[stado son los datos del pokemon que recibe la card entre las propiedades]
[removepoke y addpoke son las actions creators que realizan el dispatch]
[names es el nombre de la propiedad que tienen los personajes , la cual su valor es el nombre del personaje]

Answer (score 0):

Parece que el problema esta en el `operador condicional ternario` y en el cierre de la `expresión JSX`, dentro de la pieza de código del botón:

```
{movies.filter(x => x.names === stado.names).length > 0 & <button onClick={()=>removePoke(stado)} className="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrash}/> remove</button>}
    : <button  className="btn btn-success btn-sm" onClick={(e)=>addFavPoke(stado)} ><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faStar}/> Fav</button>
```

Aquí, el simbolo `&` no es válido:

```
{movies.filter(x => x.names === stado.names).length > 0 &
```

Debería ser `?`:

```
{movies.filter(x => x.names === stado.names).length > 0 ?
```

Luego, el cierre de los curly braces se hace despúes de `...remove</button>} : <button...`:

```
{...<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrash}/> remove</button>}
        : <button  className="btn btn-success btn-sm" onClick={(e)=>addFavPoke(stado)} ><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faStar}/> Fav</button>
```

Y debería ir al final de toda al expresión que usa el `operador condicional ternario`:

```
{...<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrash}/> remove</button>
        : <button  className="btn btn-success btn-sm" onClick={(e)=>addFavPoke(stado)} ><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faStar}/> Fav</button>}
```

Entonces, esa pieza de código debería ir de esta forma:

```
 {
  movies.filter(x => x.names === stado.names).length > 0 ? <button onClick=    {()=>removePoke(stado)} className="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrash}/> remove</button>
        : <button  className="btn btn-success btn-sm" onClick={(e)=>addFavPoke(stado)} ><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faStar}/> Fav</button>
}
```

Dime si esto fue de ayuda, estoy tratando de emular el problema de mi lado y noté este pequeño detalle antes de pasar a construir las funciones `connect`.